# How to put footer text on the same line as page number with html-to-docx nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, npm, footer, docx

I am trying to generate a footer with the html-to-docx library.

I want to put the page number on the same line as the rest of the footer content, but it makes a line break, that is, it puts the number and the rest in the next line.

```
    var headerHTMLString = event.header;
    var footerHTMLString = '';

    var footerContent = event.footer;
    var showFooter = false;
    var num_page = false;

    if(event.number_page == 1){
      num_page = true;
      showFooter = true;
    }

    if(footerContent !==""){
      footerHTMLString = '<div style="font-size: 7px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">';
      if (event.number_page == 1) {
        var no_page = '<span style="text-align: right; flex: 1;display: inline-block;"></span>';
        footerHTMLString = footerHTMLString + no_page + footerContent;
      }
      else{
        footerHTMLString = footerHTMLString + footerContent;
      }

      footerHTMLString = footerHTMLString + '</div>';
      showFooter = true;
    }

    const fileBuffer = await HTMLtoDOCX(htmlString, headerHTMLString, {
    table: { row: { cantSplit: true } },
    footer: showFooter,
    header: true,
    pageNumber: num_page}, footerHTMLString );
```

I understand that to display the page number, the library recognizes the space for it, which is the "no_page" string.

Example of how the footer appears when downloading the document:

[image]

Comment: Before diving deeper, try to simplify your footer styles. Strip away unnecessary CSS and see if the most basic structure causes the same issue. If Flexbox does not work as expected, consider using tables. Tables are well-supported in DOCX files. Create a single-row, two-cell  table. Put the page number in one cell and the footer content in the other. `<table style="width:100%; font-size: 7px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: left;">YOUR_FOOTER_CONTENT</td>
    <td style="text-align: right;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>`